# How to squeeze out the performance out of NodeJS web requests?

Tags: node.js, performance, http, optimization, node-request

Alright so my goal is to do HTTPS request to a web page as fast as I can.

I have this web page and I'm trying to get it's contents, currently Node 'request' module takes ~700ms to do the request.

I have tried multiple applications like Insomnia (170ms to same page), tried writing requests in C# (100-300ms to same page) and tried different Node modules with no luck.

So I was wondering, how would one go about squeezing as much performance as they can from Node web requests?

Comment: To get a good answer to this question, you should share a (minimal) example so we can run it too. 300ms for a hello world page is a lot, so you must be doing other things as well. We can't guess what those things are.

Comment: @Evert alright so let's say http://example.com/ from Insomnia it takes ~100ms on my network to get it but in Node it takes 300ms for it it's just empty .js file with request.

Comment: I don't really know insomnia.. is it a node.js framework? 300ms is _not normal_ for serving a basic, static page.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. You are trying to do a HTTP request, not a response.

Comment: @Evert Insomnia is something like Postman, it's made for sending requests, I mentioned Insomnia because it shows me time it took the request. It might be little bit slow because my internet speed is not the best, but NodeJS is clearly slower than C# and Insomnia/Postman/Brower

Comment: So the 'most basic' HTTP client in node.js is from the built-in http package. In theory that one should be the fastest, because any other node.js package would really just use that library and build their own layer on top. Have you tried that? A 200ms difference still seems high.

Comment: It's just 50ms performance gain, not a huge boost. I'm really confused because the requests take too long, I expected it to be 50ms difference from browser

Comment: Could you fire up something like wireshark and see where the time is spent? For example, maybe it's a slow DNS lookup (your browser might have it cached)